# Fail to pass value to array from html to PHP

Tags: php, html

Im new in PHP and i have face some problems in coding. Im going to code a form for submitting employees' details. There is checkbox in my form but i fail to pass the value of my checkbox to PHP file for displaying the details.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="readForm.php">
        <span>Title: </span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="title[]" value="prof">Prof
        <input type="checkbox" name="title[]" value="dr">Dr
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is my HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Title: </td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
                            if(is_array(!empty($_POST['title'])) || is_object(!empty($_POST['title']))) {
                                foreach($_POST['title'] as $value){
                                echo $value.'<br/>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Hint: the result of `!empty` is never an array or an object.

Comment: Shouldn't `title` logically be a radio button or select field?  I don't typically see people called "Prof. Dr. Elon Musk".

Answer (score 3):

empty() function returns bool value to is_array and is_object. So it s never been an array

```
<?php
                    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
                        if(is_array($_POST['title']) || is_object($_POST['title'])) {
                            foreach($_POST['title'] as $value){
                            echo $value.'<br/>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ?>
```